# Making a Matrix in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wrote the code and it gives this error:

> list index is out of range

```
n = int(input("Enter the order of the matrix:"))
matrix = []
count = 0
spam = 0
while spam < n + 1:
    while count < n + 1:
        j = int(input("Enter the element:"))
        matrix[spam][count] = j
        count = count + 1
    spam = spam + 1
print matrix
```

Comment: How can you expect to use it like a 2D matrix when you have'nt declared one ? You should have searched it first.

Answer (score 1):

Corrected code:

```
n = int(input("Enter the order of the matrix:"))
#Mistake 1: You have not declared a 2D matrix
matrix = [[None for x in range(n)] for x in range(n)] 
count = 0
spam = 0
#Mistake 2: spam and count should be less than n
while spam < n:
    while count < n:
        j = int(input("Enter the element:"))
        matrix[spam][count] = j
        count = count + 1
    count = 0
    spam = spam + 1
print matrix
```

Answer (score 1):

You declare `matrix` to be a list which is fine, but you forgot to declare `matrix[spam]` to also be a list. And to *add* and element to a list, you must use append instead of simply setting a non-existent index.

You could simply fix with:

```
n=int(input("Enter the order of the matrix:"))
matrix=[]
count=0
spam=0
while spam<n+1:
    matrix.append([])  # <= add an empty list
    while count<n+1:
        j=int(input("Enter the element:"))
        matrix[spam].append(j)
        count=count+1
    spam=spam+1
print matrix
```

This way would be useable even if dimensions were not known *a priori*.

Comment: `spam < n` and `count < n`, he is starting with `spam = 0` and `count = 0`

Answer (score 0):

```
def seqmatrix(matrix):
    print ' '
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        print matrix[i]
    print

def main():
    matrix = [[random.randrange(10)]*4 for i in range(4)]
    print seqmatrix(matrix)
```

Answer (score 0):

As others said, the problem with your code is that you don't create the lists for the rows of the matrix. However, please note that implementing a matrix as a list of lists is very inefficient, except as a learning exercise. The [`numpy` module](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/index.html) has an excellent implementation of n-dimensional arrays that are both efficient and intuitive to use. For example:

```
import numpy as np

n = int(input("Enter the order of the matrix:"))
matrix = np.zeros((n, n))
for spam in xrange(n):
    for count in xrange(n):
        num = int(input("Enter the element:"))
        matrix[spam][count] = num
print matrix
```